# Consumir API (JSON) em campos de formulário, como fazer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, formulário

Olá, amigos programadores.

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Tenho que utilizar em um projeto o API que consta os dados da Tabela Fipe em formato JSON (http://deividfortuna.github.io/fipe/).

Quero que meu form tenha quatro campos, sendo eles: Marca, Modelo, Ano e Valor.

Quanto seleciono a Marca do Carro (Moto ou Caminhão), o campo Modelo mostrará os itens relacionados àquela marca. Quando selecionar o modelo do carro, o terceiro campo com o ano irá abrir. Por fim, quando seleciono o ano, o último campo deve exibir o valor deste veículo.

Eu não consegui fazer nada até agora, apesar de tentativas. Nem vou expor meu código pois preciso de ajuda do zero. É importante isso, pois preciso implementar essa função em um projeto de classificados de veículos.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Comment: poste o código daquilo que já tentou na mesma. Pode ser meio caminho andando para lhe ajudar a alcançar o pretendido.

Comment: Basicamente está pedindo para alguém fazer o seu trabalho.

Comment: Não, não quero que ninguém faça o meu trabalho. Apenas gostaria de um "passo-a-passo", para entender melhor o processo e analisar o que eu estava fazendo certo ou onde errei.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer algo assim para consumir a API, usando o jQuery, a parte da dinâmica dos combos é com você, pois isso exige tempo e dedicação para o desenvolvimento, acredito que este seja o seu trabalho. Mas por sorte, você poderá encontrar alguns exemplos funcionais já mastigados pela Internet. Procure por termos de "como popular combobox dinamicamente".  [**Este site**](http://www.aoc.com.br/assistencia-tecnica) tem um exemplo deste tipo de funcionamento, analise o código fonte que ele tem a implementação para você:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="/enviar" name="formul">
    <div id="form"></div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.getJSON('https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas', function(data) {

    var select = '<select name="modelos">\
                  <option>Selecione...</option>';
    for (var i in data) {

         select += '<option value="'+data[i].codigo +'">'+ data[i].nome + '</option>';

    }
    select += '</select>';
    $('#form').html(select);

});
```

## Veja funcionando aqui

Comment: Perfeita sua resposta. Eu estava pecando na hora de implementar no form, para abrir os campos que eu desejo retorno das informações. Assim ficou mais claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Oi @MarcosPaulo,  se minha resposta te ajudou, marque-a de que ele serviu para o seu propósito. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma opção usando apenas JavaScript (sem dependência ao jQuery).

```js
var form = {};
form.fipe = document.getElementById("fipe");
form.marcas = document.getElementById("marcas");
form.modelos = document.getElementById("modelos");
form.anos = document.getElementById("anos");
form.fieldset = document.getElementById("veiculo");

form.veiculo = {};
form.veiculo.valor = document.getElementById("veiculo_valor");
form.veiculo.marca = document.getElementById("veiculo_marca");
form.veiculo.modelo = document.getElementById("veiculo_modelo");
form.veiculo.anomodelo = document.getElementById("veiculo_anomodelo");
form.veiculo.combustivel = document.getElementById("veiculo_combustivel");
form.veiculo.codigofipe = document.getElementById("veiculo_codigofipe");
form.veiculo.mesreferencia = document.getElementById("veiculo_mesreferencia");
form.veiculo.tipoveiculo = document.getElementById("veiculo_tipoveiculo");
form.veiculo.siglacombustivel = document.getElementById("veiculo_siglacombustivel");

var getJSON = function (url, sucesso, erro) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
  httpRequest.responseType = "json";
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        if (sucesso) sucesso(httpRequest.response);
      } else {
        if (erro) erro(httpRequest.status, httpRequest.statusText);
      }
    }
  });

  httpRequest.send();
}

var getMarcas = function () {
  var url = 'https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/';
  getJSON('https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas', function (marcas) {

    form.marcas.innerHTML = "";
    form.marcas.disabled = null;

    var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
    selectOption.textContent = "Selecione...";
    selectOption.value = "";
    form.anos.appendChild(selectOption);

    marcas.forEach(function (marca, indce) {
      var optionMarca = document.createElement("option");
      optionMarca.textContent = marca.nome;
      optionMarca.value = marca.codigo;
      form.marcas.appendChild(optionMarca);
    });   

  }, function (errorCode, errorText) {

  });
}

var getModelos = function () {
  var url = 'https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/' + form.marcas.value + '/modelos';
  var selectOption = form.modelos.querySelector("option");
  selectOption.textContent = "Carregando Marcas";

  getJSON(url, function (modelos) {

    form.modelos.innerHTML = "";
    form.modelos.disabled = null;

    var optionModelo = document.createElement("option");
    optionModelo.textContent = "Selecione...";
    optionModelo.value = "";
    form.modelos.appendChild(optionModelo);

    var optionAno = document.createElement("option");
    optionAno.textContent = "Selecione um Modelo";
    optionAno.value = "";
    form.anos.appendChild(optionAno);

    modelos.modelos.forEach(function (modelo, indce) {
      var optionModelo = document.createElement("option");
      optionModelo.textContent = modelo.nome;
      optionModelo.value = modelo.codigo;
      form.modelos.appendChild(optionModelo);
    });   

  }, function (errorCode, errorText) {

  });
}

var getAnos = function () {
  var url = 'https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/' + form.marcas.value + '/modelos/' + form.modelos.value + '/anos';
  var selectOption = form.anos.querySelector("option");
  selectOption.textContent = "Carregando Anos";

  getJSON(url, function (anos) {

    form.anos.innerHTML = "";
    form.anos.disabled = null;

    var optionAno = document.createElement("option");
    optionAno.textContent = "Selecione...";
    optionAno.value = "";
    form.anos.appendChild(optionAno);

    anos.forEach(function (ano, indce) {
      var optionAno = document.createElement("option");
      optionAno.textContent = ano.nome;
      optionAno.value = ano.codigo;
      form.anos.appendChild(optionAno);
    });   

  }, function (errorCode, errorText) {

  });
}

var getVeiculo = function () {
  var url = 'https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/' + form.marcas.value + '/modelos/' + form.modelos.value + '/anos/' + form.anos.value;  

  getJSON(url, function (veiculo) {
    form.fieldset.disabled = "";
    form.veiculo.valor.value = veiculo.Valor;
    form.veiculo.marca.value = veiculo.Marca;
    form.veiculo.modelo.value = veiculo.Modelo;
    form.veiculo.anomodelo.value = veiculo.AnoModelo;
    form.veiculo.combustivel.value = veiculo.Combustivel;
    form.veiculo.codigofipe.value = veiculo.CodigoFipe;
    form.veiculo.mesreferencia.value = veiculo.MesReferencia;
    form.veiculo.tipoveiculo.value = veiculo.TipoVeiculo;
    form.veiculo.siglacombustivel.value = veiculo.SiglaCombustivel;
  }, function (errorCode, errorText) {

  });
}

form.marcas.addEventListener("change", function (event) {    
  form.modelos.disabled = "disabled";
  form.anos.disabled = "disabled";
  form.fieldset.disabled = "disabled";

  form.anos.innerHTML = "";
  var optionAno = document.createElement("option");
  optionAno.textContent = "Selecione um Modelo";
  optionAno.value = "";
  form.anos.appendChild(optionAno);

  if (form.marcas.value) {
    getModelos();
  } else {
    form.modelos.innerHTML = "";
    var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
    selectOption.textContent = "Selecione uma Marca";
    selectOption.value = "";
    form.modelos.appendChild(selectOption);
  }
});

form.modelos.addEventListener("change", function (event) {    
  form.anos.disabled = "disabled";
  form.fieldset.disabled = "disabled";

  if (form.modelos.value) {
    getAnos();
  } else {
    form.anos.innerHTML = "";
    var optionAno = document.createElement("option");
    optionAno.textContent = "Selecione um Modelo";
    optionAno.value = "";
    form.anos.appendChild(optionAno);
  }
});

form.anos.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  form.fieldset.disabled = "disabled";

  if (form.anos.value) {
    form.fieldset.disabled = "disabled";

    getVeiculo();
  } else {

  }
});

getMarcas();
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 280px;  
}

fieldset div { 
  clear: both;
}
fieldset div label {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form id="fipe" method="post" action="enviar" >
  <div>
    <select id="marcas" name="marcas" disabled="disabled">
      <option>Carregando Marcas</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="modelos" name="modelos" disabled="disabled">
      <option>Selecione uma Marca</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="anos" name="anos" disabled="disabled">
      <option>Selecione um Modelo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <fieldset id="veiculo" disabled="disabled">
    <div>
      <label>
        Valor:
        <input id="veiculo_valor" name="veiculo.valor" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Marca:
        <input id="veiculo_marca" name="veiculo.marca" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Modelo:
        <input id="veiculo_modelo" name="veiculo.modelo" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Ano Modelo:
        <input id="veiculo_anomodelo" name="veiculo.anomodelo" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Combustivel:
        <input id="veiculo_combustivel" name="veiculo.combustivel" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Codigo Fipe:
        <input id="veiculo_codigofipe" name="veiculo.codigofipe" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Mes Referencia:
        <input id="veiculo_mesreferencia" name="veiculo.mesreferencia" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Tipo Veiculo:
        <input id="veiculo_tipoveiculo" name="veiculo.tipoveiculo" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Sigla Combustivel:
        <input id="veiculo_siglacombustivel" name="veiculo.siglacombustivel" type="text" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>  
</form>
```

Comment: Muito bom modelo de código. Vou estudar suas linhas, pois comigo funciona assim: preciso ver para entender. Ficou muito clara sua resposta. Obrigado mesmo.